# How i can use the string in switch case as an action?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to code a Calculator on Java but in the switch statement, it takes the operation as a String, how can I transform it into an action?

```
switch(op) {
    case 1: operation = "res= a + b";
    break;
    case 2: operation = "res = a - b";
    break;
    case 3: operation = "res = a * b";
    break;
    case 4: operation = "res = a / b";
    break;
}
  
System.out.println(operation);
```

If I remove the quotes it says that I haven't initialized the variables. They are asked after choosing the operation.

EDIT:
I was applying the wrong logic to the program.

Comment: You would need to tell as what an 'action' is. It should be some class, right?

Comment: Please rephrase your question; it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The error you report is that the variables are not initialized.  Your code snippet is missing some key information - how and where are the variables declared and initialized.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your example isn't complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't perform the operation until you have the arguments:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import java.util.*;

class t1 {
    static void calc(Scanner in) {

        System.out.print("Operation: ");
        int op = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("a: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("b: ");
        int b = in.nextInt();

        int res = 0;

        switch(op) {
            case 1:
                res = a + b;
                break;
            case 2:
                res = a - b;
                break;
            case 3:
                res = a * b;
                break;
            case 4:
                res = a / b;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid operation");
                System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println(res);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            calc(in);
        }
    }
}
```

You could verify the operation before asking for the operands, with an additional switch statement.

There are ways to set the operation before obtaining the operands, but it's best to learn to walk before you run.